# Is there a closed list of HTML tags and CSS styles that can load remote content?

Tags: html, css, tags, html-email, remote-access

In the backend of our company we are programming a page to see received emails.

We want to protect our users from being tracked by email senders, therefore the displayed HTML should not load images, javascripts, remote CSS and so on.

### Investigation

The initial idea was to protect the remote content by setting some sort of "windowed / sandboxed" viewer (all our agents use Thunderbird in a controlled version, so we don't need to code it generically for all browsers).

Nevertheless, it seems impossible. Acording to this question [How can I prevent an iframe displaying an email to load images and other email trackers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805547/how-can-i-prevent-an-iframe-displaying-an-email-to-load-images-and-other-email-t) we can't prevent the browser to load it, so we must pre-parse the HTML.

### Question

What tags hould I strip?

I wonder if there's a "closed list" of HTML tags that could force remote content loading.

For example it is clear that any javascript from the email will be removed. The same way we will remove all the `<IMG>` tags preventing the `src=` attribute to make a remote call. Yes, we know, the emails will look ugly without the fancy images, but we need to protect against tracking over "making a nice cool display".

### Already explored

We know we could discard the HTML version of the email and stick to the text-version.

But there are senders that only send in HTML instead of text+HTML. We would like to conserve "a bit of formatting" (font sizes, colors, tables, bold, italics, etc) and we agree to "kill" some things like remote styling (only allow local one), remote images, etc.

We are wondering if...

either a) we need to do an investigation by ourselves about the tags to be removed and tags to be left inside the HTML

or either b) there's any known closed list telling "the HTML elements that can cause remote loading are this and that".

### Edit

As noted by @NevNein, there are non-tag things that could trigger remote calls, as for example `<div style="background-image: url('https://some.tracking.link')"></div>`

So the question is broadened to:

Is there any closed list of html-tags and css-styles that can trigger remote calls in the browser?

Comment: Not directly related to HTML tags, but removing remote styles is not enough if you totally want to avoid external calls, for example `<div style="background-image: url('https://some.tracking.link')"></div>` will trigger a network call in the browser.

Comment: Agree, NevNein, I'm going to edit the question to broaden it to any "thing" even not being tags. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that you don't have to worry about `iframe` or `javaScript` since most email clients disable both of them.

The issue with disabling images would be some emails have content that is only in the image.

A few tags to strip would include `link` `img` `background-image` `background`. A good guide to what tags are supported with email clients can be found at: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: It's the other way around. Maybe I did not express clearly. It's not about supporting "other email clients" but building our own email viewer inside our web-based admin panel. The "viewer" is what we'll build and we want to know what tags we need to strip from the email body before sending it to the browser to ensure no remote content is lodaded.